# Are the set of all convergent geometric series whose sum is a rational number is countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, relations, first-countable

I tried this way: As the sum of convergent geometric series is $\frac{a}{1-r}$ and $-1<r<1$.

Moreover sum is also a rational number. So $a$ and $r$ should be rational numbers. As rational numbers are countable. We can say $a$ and $r$ are countable, which means the set of series is also countable.

> But my doubt is if $a= 0.333.....$ and $r= 0.7777....$ , where both
>   are irrationals. Sum will be rational in that case also
>   $(0.333/1-0.777=1)$. In that case $a$ and $r$ need not be rational
>   which means they will be uncountable.

I am stuck here.

Comment: Here is a quick guide to MathJax to format your posts on this website : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think you didn't finish writing your question.

Comment: Are the set of all convergent geometric series whose sum is a rational number is countable or not? That's my question sir

Comment: @SaketGurjar the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3695894/revisions) makes it look like you put in almost all of the relevant mathematical content of this question. If true, I think this is probably inappropriate - please consider whether you are really preserving the goals of the post's owner. Also, the mathematical content of the edit is wrong - both those numbers are rational and they don't sum to 1.

Comment: @KReiser The words there aren''t mine.....these were in the question but not displaying for some reason......I think there was some glitch in the website, which made it not show the words, that it 'looks like'  I added (check the 'source' for the original question through the edit history to see what I am talking about). I simply added some indentation that seemed to repair it.

Comment: @SaketGurjar huh, that's weird. Thanks for the explanation, and my apologies if I came off too accusative.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the set is uncountable. I will make use of the fact that the set of irrational numbers $x$ such that $0<x<1$ is uncountable.

Let $r$ be an irrational number between $0$ and $1$. $r$ will be the common ratio of the series.

Now, we want to find a number $u$ to be the first term of the series, such that the sum of the series is rational.

That is, we need $\frac{u}{1-r}=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p$ and $q$.

Well, just let $u=\frac{p}{q}\times(1-r)$. Then the sum of the series will be $\frac{p}{q}$. Note that $u$ is also an irrational number, since $r$ is irrational.

Since there are an uncountable number of choices for $r$, there are an uncountable number of geometric series with rational sum.